# Multiple (document).ready(function) issue

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with multiple

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

I tried a dozen related question/answers here but no luck. If i take one of the below out, other works and vice versa.

I cant figure out my issue with this

The code is

```js
/* 
 * Toggles search on and off
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".search-toggle").click(function(){
        $("#search-container").slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $('.search-toggle').toggleClass('active');
        });
        // Optional return false to avoid the page "jumping" when clicked
        return false;
    });

 /* 
 * Toggles Match tab
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".control-all ").click(function(){
        $(".match-events").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            $('.control-all ').toggleClass('active');
        });
        // Optional return false to avoid the page "jumping" when clicked
        return false;
    });
```

Any solutions for this to work?
Regards

Comment: multiple document ready wont create problem, unless you dont have jquery properly installed

Comment: Post your HTML sample.

Comment: and your code has errors.

Comment: I couldn't explain and put all the codes inside edit so to keep it clean and to see it better here it is http://pastebin.com/3ZFHz0Vu

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly closed jQuery(document).ready(function($)

```
/* 
 * Toggles search on and off
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".search-toggle").click(function(){
        $("#search-container").slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $('.search-toggle').toggleClass('active');
        });
        // Optional return false to avoid the page "jumping" when clicked
        return false;
    });
});
 /* 
 * Toggles Match tab
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".control-all ").click(function(){
        $(".match-events").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            $('.control-all ').toggleClass('active');
        });
        // Optional return false to avoid the page "jumping" when clicked
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I was trying a lot to work it out, so i missed i guess the closing part, but that it's not an issue, as it doesnt work with this.

Comment: Ok i found a problem. The last part was the issue. You pointed me in right direction. When i put the last part also inside jQuery(document).ready(function($){  it worked, stupid me , newbie mistake. Thanks all for the help